# Unable to load a Suite class

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea

[image]

Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath.

i am getting this error while trying to run scala test case. kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you show your directory structure of project and build.sbt?

Comment: Might be useful to have a look there: https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: Look like there is reported issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12564. Feel free to add information about your configuration and used versions in comments.

Comment: can you update with your build.sbt file and import statements in your test class ?

Answer (score 2):

I have same error message as yours.

What I do is:
In your test run configuration(go "Edit Configuration" > "Use classpath ... of module") select the right module at place the image show.
[image]

At least this solve my problem that I target to wrong module. May it help you.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the same problem by checking "Use SBT" option in test run configuration under Edit Configuration>Test Class